# Solving $AX=B$ matrix equation with zero diagonal constraint

Tags: matrices

Is there a solution for $AX=B$ matrix equation with zero diagonal constraint, such that: $X_{ii} = 0$ ?
where, $A, B, X$ are $n \times n$ matrices.

Is it right to solve the equation as follows?

$X = A^{-1}B$
$X_{ii} = 0$

Comment: Is $A$ invertible?

Comment: $X=A^{-1}B$ only makes sense if $A$ is invertible. But in that case, the diagonal values of $X$ are already determined by $A^{-1}B$ and cannot be separately constrained. So the only way this system can possibly be solvable is if either $A^{-1}B$ happens to have zero diagonal part or $A$ is not invertible (and therefore $A^{-1}B$ is not defined).

Comment: If it helps, here is an equivalent way to think about this problem: a solution $X$ to this equation exists if and only if for $1 \le j \le n$, the $j$-th column of $B$ lies in the span of the columns, excluding the $j$-th column, of $A$.

Comment: @Itay4, Yes $A$ is invertible.